# Python directory recursion with conditional function

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, yield

I am working on a function that will recurse a directory tree from a given starting point over a given number of directory levels and return files and/or folders as a list. I want to have the option of passing a condition to this function to be evaluated for each file or folder before it is added to the list. For example, I may want my function to return only a list of files with the extension '.py', or I might want only filenames that match with some regex expression.

My code below works fine without passing any conditions to `get_items()`, but when using conditions I am unable to get any files and folders below the top directory, regardless of what `recursion_level` is set to.

If the condition and condition args are set to `None`, the code below prints a list of all '.py' files found in the top four directory levels. With the given arguments, though, only '.py' files in the top directory are captured.

It seems that the code under `if depth != 0:` in `def get_items()` is not being executed when a condition is given

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python

import os
import os.path as path
import re

###  --------------------------------------------------
###  DEFINE DIRECTORY RECURSION METHODS:

# Get files and/or directories from input dir (defines a generator object)
# (Solution inspired by post & comments at stackoverflow.com/questions/35315873)
def get_items(input_dir,mode='f',depth=0,condition=None,arg=None,show_hidden=False):
    dirs,files = {},{}
    # Use dictionary to assign generator outputs from mode
    modes = {'f':files,'d':dirs,'w':(input_dir,dirs,files)}
    dir_list = os.listdir(input_dir)
#   print '\nDIRECTORY "{}" CONTAINS {} FILES.'.format(path.basename(input_dir),len(dir_list))
    for name in dir_list:
        # Ignore hidden files (Mac OS)
        if name.startswith('.') and not show_hidden:
            continue
#       print '\t',name
        path_name = path.join(input_dir,name)
        # Check if file satisfies the given conditional function
        if condition and not condition(*((path_name,arg) if arg else (path_name,))):
            continue
        # Append item to appropriate dictionary with 'name' as key and 'path' as value
        (dirs if path.isdir(path_name) else files)[name]=path_name
    yield modes[mode]
    # If depth not yet zero, call the function for the next level down
    if depth != 0:
#       print '\nFOUND {} SUBDIRECTORIES TO PROCESS:'.format(len(dirs))
        for d in dirs:
            for i in get_items(dirs[d],mode,depth-1,condition,arg,show_hidden):
                yield i

# Parse output from get_items() to simple lists
def parse_trees(dir_trees):
    all_dirs,all_files = [],[]
    for tree in dir_trees:
        obj_type = type(tree)
        # If a tuple object is encountered (walk mode)
        if obj_type is tuple:
#           top = tree[0]
            dirs,files = [branch.values() for branch in tree[1:]]
        # If a dictionary is encountered (files or dirs mode)
        elif obj_type is dict:
            dirs,files = [],[]
            for branch in tree:
                # Access dictionary values to get path
                branch_path = tree[branch]
                # Append path to appropriate list
                (dirs if path.isdir(branch_path) else files).append(branch_path)
#               print branch
        all_dirs += dirs
        all_files += files
    return all_files,all_dirs


###  --------------------------------------------------
###  DEFINE FILE CONDITION CHECKS:

# Check the basename of a given file for a regex pattern match
def pattern_check(file_path,pattern):
    filename = path.split(file_path)[1]
#   basename,ext = path.splitext(filename)
    return (True if re.search(pattern,filename) else False)

# Check for the extension in a given list argument
def ext_check(file_path,extensions):
    filename = path.split(file_path)[1]
    basename,ext = path.splitext(filename)
    return (True if ext in extensions else False)


###  --------------------------------------------------
###  EXECUTE:

mydir = os.getcwd()

recursion_depth = 3
condition_method,condition_arg = ext_check,['.py']

dir_trees = get_items(mydir,'f',recursion_depth,condition_method,condition_arg,False)
file_list,dir_list = parse_trees(dir_trees)

if dir_list:
    print '\nDIRS:'
    for d in dir_list:
        print '\t',d

if file_list:
    print '\nFILES:'
    for f in file_list:
        print '\t',f

print '\n'
```

Comment: Uh, is there something wrong with `os.walk`?

Comment: This is essentially reworked from os.walk, however I want to be able to specify how many levels to recurse

Comment: Can't you just re-use `os.walk` and `break` when you are at a certain depth?

Comment: I'm sure i could -- I suppose that i was thinking it would be more processor-efficient to modify `os.walk` to be tailored to my needs. I dont know much about python, though, and your suggestion would certainly be more readable. I will try that; i would still like to know why the above code wont run properly